# Android Drag Drop 2D on Canvas

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-canvas, crop

I want to create crop function but I don't want to crop image directly. I just want to get x and y value from Rectangle 2D object that place over the image.

How can I create drag drop Rectangle over image and get X,Y position of Rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `OnTouchListener(MotionEvent event)` then you can listen for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` when the down and up triggers, grab the event's x and y position. You can then use this to create a `Rect()` which you can use then to crop the image by creating a bitmap from canvas using the rect as the bounds.